# Android toolbar icon sizes

Tags: java, android, css, xml, icons

Struggling to make the lower tool bar icons fit evenly across the row.

[image]

As you can see from the image above, the icons aren't fitting the row evenly.

Can anyone help me with the height and width parameters

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/default_elevation">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/img_toolbar_logo3" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="@dimen/default_elevation"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notis_white"
    />
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notis_white"
    />
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notis_white"
    />
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notis_white"
    />
<ImageButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notis_white"
    />
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol Can someone help me fit the image buttons evenly across the whole toolbar